# Handle Entitlement on Prism Modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

We are developing our application in WPF,Prism & C# and using MVVM pattern

I am developing entitlement part where we have decided entitlement should be on Screen level[This is final and we cant change this].

We have 3 modules, Admin,Transactions,Reports

Below is screen names modulewise:-

```
Admin - DropDown Maintenance,User Maintenance etc.
Transactions - Products,Orders etc.
Reports - Products Reports,Order Reports etc.
```

we have more than 50 screens in our application

Since entitlement is based on Screen level so I have decided to make a class of Constants or Enums.

I am also thinking if user dont have access on all screens of particular module then we should not show that module.This is the problem not getting any good idea of implementing it.

I need a proper structure by which I can easily identify the module of particular screen because I have entitlement on screen not on module.

Oneway I thought of is I can create separate enums modulewise but the problem is enum doesnt support inhertence and the entitlement method which I have created is common for all screens.

```
public enum Reports //module name
{
ProductReport, //screen name
OrderReport //screen name
}

public enum Admin //module name
{
DropDownMaintenance, //screen name
UserMaintenance //screen name
}
```

My method to verify entitlement

```
public bool VerifyEntitlement(string screen,AccessEnum access) {}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Displaying Views in a Region Programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec38)? It sounds like you need to inject views based on some precondition, but I can't really say for sure without more information.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I was thinking to implement